# Is the existence of jinn well-known?

Tags: jinn

On the TV series *Jinn*, some evidence suggests that knowledge of the existence of jinn is fairly widespread. For instance, when the tour guide is talking about jinn, they give a very historical presentation, talking about how humans drove jinn out and so forth (but that could just be their personal beliefs, of course). And when students ask about the evolution of jinn while the teacher is talking about the theory of evolution in class, the teacher doesn't take any issue with the various facts that the students bring up about jinn, such as that they were the first species on the planet and didn't evolve, although he seems to see the discussion as a distraction from the main topic. And, for that matter, pretty much all the students seem to take the existence of jinn, at least at one time, as a given in that discussion as well. Obviously, the existence of jinn is canonical in Islam, but this isn't a religous school.

On the other hand, Layla thinks Mira is crazy when she brings up a jinni as an explanation for Nassar's behavior, and people tend to dismiss the class jinn conspiracy theorist, which would tend to point toward a setting more like the real-world, where jinn aren't exactly part of secular history.

Is the series set in an alternate history in which the actions of jinn in the distant past are relatively well-known historically? Or is it basically the real world, where belief in the existence of jinn is less common and more a matter of how religiously observant one is?